# FileNet developing applet for Workflows

Tags: workflow, filenet-p8, filenet-workplace

I'm developing an applet which will be used as step processor for FileNet Workflows. I wrote some simple applets based on swing and awt and compiled sample applet from IBM documentation, but every integration tries end with the same result - "System error". I'm making configuration changes point by point. I think configuration is exactly the problem I've got.

Can somebody help me with configuring just one applet? step by step?

@Add1
The problem with error is that it's just "System error" and it's all.

OK. Steps which i've done:

1. Made an applet based on SWING, just 1 JLabel and 2 JButtons.
2. Compiled an applet. Applet class is `org.Applet`
3. Copied .jar with applet to `filenet_installation_directory\WorkplaceXT\download`
4. In `filenet_installation_directory\WorkplaceXT\eprocess\stepprocs\java` copied ootb folder (FileNet applet) and changed name to myApplet. Also name of .jsp file in that directory.
5. Opened .jsp file and make changes adding version to jarVersionValues variable, changing applet class name in appletClassName property to org.Applet and changing .jar name in jarArchiveValues property to name of .jar with applet.
6. In `filenet_installation_directory\Workplace\UI-INF\jsp\ui\eprocess\stepprocs\java` copied ootb folder and changed name of folder to myApplet and name of .jsp page inside directory to myApplet.jsp
7. In .jsp file set `WcmString topic = new WcmString("server.myApplet_jsp.topic", "My Custom Step Processor");`
8. After that I'm adding an applet to Process Configuration Console. In region properties, in steps tab I'm adding new step processor, type java, class `org.myApplet`, path `java\myApplet\myApplet.jsp`
9. After that I have step processor in Process Designer, but when I start a workflow and try to start a task than a "System Error" appears.

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to ask for step-by-step instructions at SO. Specify the steps you made and provide enough context and details about the error you get.

Comment: I added some more information about my problem in first post.

Comment: Where does this "System Error" actually happen? Client- or server-side? Anything in Java Applet console log, Workplace.log, WebSphere SystemOut.log?

Comment: When I enter the step in WorkplaceXT, than it appears without any sign of loading applet or something. Nothing in WebSphere and Workplace logs. It looks like .jsp page isn't loaded into websphere? Any ideas how to check that?

Comment: Oh my god... I found a solution :) That's my mistake. I'm developing one shot application, so I don't know FileNet enought. I copied files to FileNet installation directory not to WebSphere directory. Your question about WebSphere logs created a new searching path. Now I've some new errors but happily I've got some additional information from java applet. Thank you for your hint.